# How to update fields in a model without creating a new record in django?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model in django that I want to update only, that is, when I call it and set the data, it will not create a new record, only update the existing one. How can I do this? Here is what I have:

```
class TemperatureData(models.Model):   
    date = models.DateTimeField()   
    value = models.PositiveIntegerField()   
    alert = models.BooleanField()
```

Answer (score 185, accepted):

If you get a model instance from the database, then calling the save method will always update that instance.  For example:

```
t = TemperatureData.objects.get(id=1)
t.value = 999  # change field
t.save() # this will update only
```

If your goal is prevent any INSERTs, then you can override the `save` method, test if the primary key exists and raise an exception.  See the following for more detail:

- [How Django knows to UPDATE vs. INSERT](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/instances/#how-django-knows-to-update-vs-insert)

Comment: isn't there another solution? This seems more like "SELECT / UPDATE" than simply "UPDATE"

Comment: How do you update all the fields of the record, with a new request that was send. Lets say the record with it's id was pulled into a form, one field was changed and it needs to be updated, do I have to run through every field to see if it changed?

Answer (score 38):

You should do it this way ideally

```
t = TemperatureData.objects.get(id=1)
t.value = 999
t.save(['value'])
```

This allow you to specify which column should be saved and rest are left as they currently are in database.
(https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/4102)!

Comment: I like this answer, but with the current version you need to use `t.save(update_fields=['value'])` to [force an update](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/instances/#specifying-which-fields-to-save).

Answer (score 30):

Sometimes it may be required to execute the update atomically that is using one update request to the database without reading it first.

Also `get`-`set attribute`-`save` may cause problems if such updates may be done concurrently or if you need to set the new value based on the old field value.

In such cases [query expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/expressions/) together with `update` may by useful:

```
TemperatureData.objects.filter(id=1).update(value=F('value') + 1)
```

To update multiple fields:

```
TemperatureData.objects.filter(id=1).update(
    value=F('value') + 1,
    another_value=F('another_value')+1
)
```

Comment: This is the best answer. For example also according to https://www.webforefront.com/django/singlemodelrecords.html (search "update")

Comment: can I use multiple values liek this and update them all at once?

Comment: @Pfinnn yes, the answer is updated with the example

Answer (score 4):

Django has some documentation about that on their website, see: [Saving changes to objects](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#saving-changes-to-objects). To summarize:

> .. to save changes to an object that's already in the database, use `save()`.

Answer (score 4):

In my scenario, I want to update the status of status based on his id

```
student_obj = StudentStatus.objects.get(student_id=101)
student_obj.status= 'Enrolled'
student_obj.save()
```

Or If you want the last id from Student_Info table you can use the following.

```
student_obj = StudentStatus.objects.get(student_id=StudentInfo.objects.last().id)
student_obj.status= 'Enrolled'
student_obj.save()
```