# Django: UpdateView with unique field

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create an update profile page for my custom User model.  In my model, my email field is set to be unique.

```
class User(UserBase):
     ...
     email = models.EmailField(
            max_length=100,
            unique=True,
            blank=True,
            verbose_name='email address',
        )
```

Then in my view I have:

```
class UpdateProfileView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    template_name = 'accounts/update-profile.html'
    form_class = UpdateProfileForm
    model = User
```

The only thing that `UpdateProfileForm` does is check that the old password is different from the new one in the `clean` method.

My issue is that when I save the form I'm getting the error message `User with this Email address already exists.`.  Since it's an update view and saving a unique field that hasn't changed shouldn't it not throw this error?  If this is the correct behavior, then how do I save the form and ignore the email address if it hasn't changed.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Am I taking crazy pills, is this not a thing or a dumb question?

Comment: No one has any feedback on this?

Comment: Why don't you show us the `UpdateProfileForm` so we can get a better idea.

Comment: Right from the `form.save` [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method): "A subclass of ModelForm can accept an existing model instance as the keyword argument instance; if this is supplied, save() will update that instance. If it’s not supplied, save() will create a new instance of the specified model." Are you using the `instance` argument?

Comment: I would assume `UpdateView` does this behind the scenes.  At least that is the behavior I would expect.

Comment: Does it work when you comment out the `form_class`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `blank=True` from your User Model definition. The field definition is `null=False` by default and additionally you specify the field must be unique—it's a important field—so you don't want your form validation to allow blank values. Here is the Django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/fields/#field-options) on those attributes. `blank` is entirely a form validation thing. That alone might fix the error.

Unless you have custom form logic/validation, you don't need the `form_class` attribute on your `UpdateProfileView`. From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#model-forms): "These generic views will automatically create a ModelForm". (There is even an UpdateView example).

See if the view works without `form_class` and if it does then examine your `UpdateProfileForm` code.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some suggestions/alternatives:

1. If you stop using Generic Views (i.e. UpdateProfileView), you can then do the following steps in your logic view: if the request is a POST, take the data from the form and update your Model ([How to update fields in a model without creating a new record in django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681627/django-how-to-update-fields-in-a-model-without-creating-a-new-record))
2. Why don't you use a ModelForm instead? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/
3. Why don't you work with User from django.contrib.auth.models? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#user-objects
4. Finally, have you considered working with this already built Django registration app? http://www.michelepasin.org/blog/2011/01/14/setting-up-django-registration/

Answer (score 0):

1. Never use blank=True and unique=True, its senseless. If you want to make this field is not required in form, just do.

   ```
   class Form(forms.Form):
        ...

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
             super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
             self.fields['unique_field].required = False
   ```
2. In addition to previous answer, when u use blank=True and unique=True, the "Is already exits ... blah bla" its correct behavior, coz form accepting empty string as value and its already exists. You need to override clean_field method:

   ```
   class Form(forms.Form):
       ...

       def clean_unique_id(self):
           """
           Take new value or if its '' e.g. None take initial value 
           """
           return self.data['unique_id'] or self.initial['unique_id']
   ```