# How to modify a boolean field model in Django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I'm trying to apply an activate/deactivate feature for my posts on a blog app. Here is my model. My desire is to be able to activate the post to show it in a template but how can I change (set) the value of `is_activate` field through the view.py? Here is my model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
   slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250)
   body = models.TextField()
   is_activate = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Summarizing: I need a button which on clicking activates a post and then show it in a template with other activated posts.

Comment: What have you been able to do, in your views?

Comment: What's complicated here? Why is changing the `is_activate` field any different from changing any other fields?

Comment: @EvansMurithi beacause I need to use a buttom in a template and not through the admin

Comment: @DanielRoseman Well, some tutorial only show how to retrieve from the database and not how to set a variable

Comment: No good ones do that. The official one certainly doesn't. But even if they did, can you not work it out?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update fields in a model without creating a new record in django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681627/how-to-update-fields-in-a-model-without-creating-a-new-record-in-django)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the post by primary key

```
post = Post.objects.get(id=id)
post.is_activate = True
post.save()
```

by this code your is_activate flag will be set for this post

Comment: You mean create a new view function to set the variable or I need to do this in the same function that I retrieve each individual post?

Comment: in the same function

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
This is your **model.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
   slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250)
   body = models.TextField()
   is_activate = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

and `view.py`

```
from foldername import Post //if there are subfolders use'.' between them.
//import the other packages which u need
form=form_name  //your form name
template=template_name  //your template name
def post( self, request, *args, **kwargs ):
        try:
            form = self.form_class( request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
            new_formfile = form.save(commit=False)
            new_formfile.is_activate = true
            new_formfile.save()
        except Exception as e:
            return render(request, 'exception.html', {'exception': str(e), 'message': e.message})
```

**OR**

//another method write in try block

```
id = request.GET.get('id')
id_instance = Post.objects.get( pk = id )
form = self.form_class(request.POST, instance = id_instance)
if form.is_valid():
new_formfile = form.save(commit=False)
new_formfile.is_activate = true
new_formfile.save()
form.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

With **"update()"**, you can update **"is_activate" field** as shown below:

```py
Post.objects.filter(id=id).update(is_activate=True)
```