# Perform math in Django and databases

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-admin

I am building an inventory system using Django, right now I am adding the functionality to place an order. What I want to do is to subtract the quantity ordered from the quantity in the database. For example if someone ordered 10boxes of chips and I have 11 in my stock once I place the order on web I want the web to subtract 10 boxes from the stock. I am not really sure how to do that. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You do: `11 - 10 = 1`. Is that what you're asking? Else you need to be more elaborate. Where exactly you are facing the problem.

Comment: No of course am not asking for that, what I mean is that i might enter any value other than 10 and whatever value I enter should be subtracted from the value in the database.

Comment: Try searching for `F` function in Django ORM. That should solve your issue. Well, had you gone through the document, you would have found it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the model name is `Inventory`, `item_code` is the identification code of the ordered item, and `ordered_amount` is the amount ordered from your web interface. I would do the following:

(1) retrieve the item from inventory

`item = Inventary.objects.get(id=item_code)`

(2) update amount

`item.amount = item.amount - ordered_amount`

(3) save new value for item

`item.save()`

You can find a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681627/how-to-update-fields-in-a-model-without-creating-a-new-record-in-django).

Comment: It depends how you access the inventory, and you implement the save, as you can see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645269/concurrency-control-in-django-model